# Environment Variable Error - TypeScript, Vite, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, vite

I'm getting this error in env-options.js:4:4

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

[image]

when trying to use environment variables in my Vite/React application.

I'm using the import.meta.env syntax as per the documentation but nothing seems to work.

My Firebase config looks like this:

```
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, User } from "firebase/auth";
    import 'dotenv/config'
    
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID
    };
    
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    
    
    export { 
        app,
        auth,
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
        onAuthStateChanged
        }
    
    export type { User }
```

.env file:

```
    VITE_API_KEY="VALUE"
    VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN="VALUE"
    VITE_PROJECT_ID="VALUE"
    VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET="VALUE"
    VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="VALUE"
    VITE_APP_ID="VALUE"
```

I've tried:

- Renaming the .env file to .env.local
- Removing the quotation marks from the values in the .env file
- Adding and removing commas between lines in the .env file
- Adding import 'dotenv/config' to the firebaseConfig file
- Adding curly braces around the values in the firebaseConfig object
- Storing the value of import.meta.env to a variable and using that in
  the config

vite.config.ts

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/job-board/",
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  }
})
```

Comment: Nothing in what you have shared seems relevant to the error message of "process is undefined".  Is there anything in your code or configuration that includes the symbol/string "process" ?  Is there more to the error message, such as a full stack trace?

Comment: Okay, I've added a screenshot from the console. Hope that helps. I've searched for the keyword process in the application and it doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: What is the file `config.js` ?  Consider printing out (console.log()'ing) the value of `firebaseConfig` just before calling initializeApp() to validate it has correct values.